# How to Retrieve All comment s content on Facebook Post using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

im beginner in Facebook Graph API , i want to get all the comments of my friend's post , all what a have is the post id,
any one can guide me on how to get the comments on post
note that im familiar with Rest API/Json...

thanks in advance

Comment: First of all your friend would have to log in to your app, and grant it permission to read their posts.

Comment: Okey, thank you for the response (y)